# What am I? I am a group

Tags: riddle, word

> What am I? I am a group.
> You can't blame anyone for I being in me.
> But I might not anyway.
> It depends on how you see the sixth in the third.
> But I wasn't invoking Godwin's Law!
>
> You are not in me.
> She is not, either.
> But the second is, if you cut it.
> But not the sixtieth of a minute!
> Now, what am I, specifically?

Hint:

> If you see an ordinal number, read aloud which part(s) of the riddle you think is/are relevant.

Hint 2:

> For example, the fourth line: the sixth (beep) in the third (beep). And watch out for red herrings.

Hint 3 (quite a big hint):

> The title counts.

Comment: You're a group.

Comment: A bounty for each puzzle you post. Not sure if you have enough budget.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir I'm restoring my old questions. As you can see, I still have 222.

Comment: Do we require any knowledge of set theory to solve this?

Comment: @Petrichor no, you don't.

Comment: I think I have a clue which may help : 4th line : "it depends on how you see the sixth [sense / chakra?] in the third [eye]" - (I googled it, it's from spiritual things) and by eye it means the letter "I". So my guess is the "I" from the second line "for I being in me" is not what we think. (Not sure about the sixth sense though, it might be useless or wrong).

Comment: @Albino Correct word despite incorrect explanation.

Comment: Ok so eye is correct, right? Then I was thinking, in the line 8 that "second" is not referring to the time unit (as I understood in the line 9)
but maybe to the second part of the line 7 => either (which can be pronounced as "eye"-ther) ? Anyway, I don't think my english is good enough to pursue this riddle but it was fun! Thank you for posting it

Comment: @Albino What was correct was that the word "I" is 'interesting'. It's not to be interpreted as "eye".

Comment: The third hint makes it easier

Answer (score 6):

Could it be the word

> ITS?

*What am I? I am a group.*

> Not sure about this. A quick web search threw up various organisations called ITS Group, but none seemed particularly famous or relevant.

*You can't blame anyone for I being in me.*

> The letter I is contained in the word.

*But it might not be the case anyway.*
*It depends on how you see the third.*

> Except for its third letter, the word is "it".

*But I wasn't invoking Godwin's Law!*

> The third letter gives SS, a Nazi organisation.

*You will never be in me*
*She will never, either.*

> Wrong pronouns! Not yours or hers, but its.

*But the second is.*

> Except for its second letter, the word is "is".

*But not the sixtieth of a minute!*

> Indeed, not tha kind of second.

*Now, what am I, specifically?*

> ITS.

Comment: I have fixed the question

Comment: It's quite far away

Answer (score 2):

Without being sure, I think about

> Vowels

> You can't blame anyone for I being in me.

> Well, the letter "I" is a vowel!

> But I might not anyway.

> But it does not appear in the word "vowel".

> It depends on how you see the sixth in the third.

> The sixth vowel ("Y") is sometimes pronounced like the third ("I"), but sometimes as a consonant.

> But I wasn't invoking Godwin's Law!

> Not sure about this one…

> You are not in me.

> The letter "U" (pronounced "You") is not in the word "vowel"

> She is not, either.

> Not sure about this one… Maybe the letter "C"?

> But the second is, if you cut it.

> The second vowel ("E") is in the word "vowel". Not sure about the "cut it" part, maybe because it is not pronounced "ee" like in the alphabet (the "ee" pronounciation like in "see")? It is possible that the second refers to the letter "B", which is almost an "O" when cut?

> But not the sixtieth of a minute!

> Already said by others: not that kind of second.

Comment: Almost correct~

Comment: Do you mean that I need to work on my interpretations or to find another answer somewhat similar?

Comment: Another answer.

Answer (score 1):

My thought is:

> CODEINS

You can't blame anyone for I being in me.

> My deduction is there's the letter 'I' in the word after the answers the author gave in the comments. => "It depends on how you see the sixth in the third" was an hint, the third eye (see Hint 2) refers to that specific 'i' in the riddle.

You are not in me.
She is not, either.
But the second is

> I think that the word has to be formed with the letters of "second" but doesn't contain "you" or even "she"

By combining all the letters altogether we have

> we obtain: codeins or secondi

By deduction:
"the second is, if you cut it."
and "What am I? I am a group."

> [codeins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codeine)

Comment: Still quite far away

Answer (score 1):

Another new answer:

> Group 17 in the periodic system of chemical elements, i. e. the halogens (including hydrogen for that purpose).

What am I? I am a group.

> Whell, this is a *group* in the periodic table.

You can't blame anyone for I being in me.

> "I" (iodine) is a halogen, and this is due to the atom structure, so nobody (Mendeleev, Courtois etc.) can be blamed for it.

But I might not anyway.

> the word "halogens" contains no I's.

It depends on how you see the sixth in the third.

> Well, it depends on how you see the "A" (6th word in the riddle) in the whole group (3rd word in the riddle is "I" which refers to it). If "A" is in the group (so this must be the *word* "halogens", which contains an A), so "I" is not. On the other side, "A" is not in the group itself, but "I" is.

But I wasn't invoking Godwin's Law!

> Unsure. Probably a reference to the word "halogen" being invited by a *German*.

You are not in me.

> "U" (uranium) is not a halogen.

She is not, either.

> "S" (sulfur) and "He" (helium) are also not halogens.

But the second is, if you cut it.

> The 2nd element (helium) is not a halogen, but can be "cut" (not physically of course, and it requires a LOT of energy) into two hydrogen atoms.

But not the sixtieth of a minute!

> As pointed by others, not that kind of second.

Now, what am I, specifically?

> Hydrogen and the halogens.

Comment: Maybe Hydrogen and Halogens make "HH" which could be a reference to "Heil Hitler" (but not if we don't invoke Godwin's law)?

Answer (score 0):

New answer, 4 years later:

> you are a TEAM.

*What am I? I am a group.*

> Group = team.

*You can't blame anyone for I being in me.
*But I might not anyway.
*It depends on how you see the sixth in the third.*

> There's a common phrase 'there's no "I" in "team"', which has sometimes been updated to the following:
>
>  [image]
>
>  "Sixth in third" refers to the words in the title: the sixth word is "a" and the third word is "I", so "seeing the sixth in the third" probably refers to the above memetic image.

*But I wasn't invoking Godwin's Law!*

> Not sure about this, unless you mean Hitler was an A-Hole.

*You are not in me.

She is not, either.

But the second is, if you cut it.

But not the sixtieth of a minute!*

> "You" and "she" are also not in "team", but the second word of the title ("am") is in "team": it can be seen if you cut the word "team" in half.

*Now, what am I, specifically?*

> The word TEAM, specifically.

Comment: nope, not the correct answer

Comment: Damn, I was so sure about this one ...